# C# search tag in XML and show another tag

Tags: c#, xml, search

I have the following XML-File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <Name>Example</Name>
    <PhoneNo>0481-12345678</PhoneNo>
    <SalesPhoneNo>310<SalesPhoneNo />
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

Would it be possible to search for the PhoneNo 0481-12345678 in the XML and then only show the SalesPhoneNo 310.

Comment: use XmlDeserialize class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an XPath query to do this. For example,

```
var xml = @"<Contacts>
                <Contact>
                <Name>Example</Name>
                <PhoneNo>0481-12345678</PhoneNo>
                <SalesPhoneNo>310</SalesPhoneNo>
                </Contact>
            </Contacts>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// this will return 310
string phoneNo = '0481-12345678';
var salesPhoneNo = xDoc.XPathEvaluate("string(//Contact[PhoneNo='" + phoneNo + "']/SalesPhoneNo)");
```

Note you need to add a `using System.Xml.XPath` to use XPath query on an `XDocument`

Comment: When I try to run the script I get the following error:
xmltest3.cs(9,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `var'. I am using mcs at debian 9.

Comment: @marc494, I suppose it is unsupported in the version you're using. You could try `string salesPhoneNo = xDoc....` instead to avoid that particular problem, then it should work as long as it supports the other libraries being used.

Comment: actually `object salesPhoneNo = xDoc...`, you'll have to `ToString()` or cast to get a string from that

Comment: The script is now working, I get only the following error: " 'XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathEvaluate'" it seems some error with using System.Xml.XPath

Comment: The above is using `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. Also note `XPathEvaluate` is an extension method, so if you do switch to `XDocument`, you need to have a `using System.Xml.XPath` at the top of your script to make it work.

Comment: With the using System.Xml.XPath it is working. But now I want to add a variable instead of PhoneNo='0481-12345678'.

Comment: Is this the correct way to do this:
PhoneNo=@variable

Comment: No, you can just use string concatenation here (I've edited the answer), as far as I know XPath in C# doesn't support external parameters like SQL statements (which does mean there's an injection risk). In newer versions of C# you could use string interpolation, but you won't have that available. `String.Format` is another option if you find that neater; though neither mitigate injection risk.